# Оставить только буквы и цифры в поисковом запросе сайта!

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Суть вопрос в следующем: Пользователь вводит в поисковую строку номер `13.6АВ54:00%21` и жмет поиск!

Задача сайта перехватить эту строку, удалить лишние точки и символы, оставить только буквы и цифры: вот так - `136АВ540021`!

В случае с WordPress `$st = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/","",$st);`  в этой форме

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
  <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search products&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php  echo get_search_query(); ?>"
    name="s" />
  <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

Работает не правильно, все равно ищет с точками и ничего не находит, но в поисковой строке подменяет как надо, то есть надо два раза повторять поиск, а нужно сразу что бы искало исправленную строку!

Есть идеи?

Comment: вы показали нам бесполезную форму, но не показали как и где вы используете это свое регулярное выражение.

Comment: $st = get_search_query();
$st = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/","",$st);

и вместо get_search_query(); подставил в value" <?php echo $st; ?>".

Comment: дак вы убедились в том что сам поиск потом использует эту же функцию для получения текста запроса? то что вы вывели это в форме не имеет ничего общего с тем, что ушло в поиск, очевидно.

Comment: То есть я не там ищу? Если в курсе, подскажите где в WP это править?
уже все файлы перепробовал везде один результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте такие фильтры в functions.php:

```
function clean_search_string( $s ) {
    $s = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/", '', $s );

    return $s;
}

function get_search_query_filter( $query_var ) {
    $query_var = clean_search_string( $query_var );

    return $query_var;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_query', 'get_search_query_filter' );

function request_filter( $query_vars ) {
    if ( isset( $query_vars['s'] ) ) {
        $query_vars['s'] = clean_search_string( $query_vars['s'] );
    }

    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'request', 'request_filter' );
```

Comment: все равно нужно два раза нажимать на поиск! Но уже исключает символы везде и в результатах поиска.

Comment: Извиняюсь что прошу сделать за меня тонкую работу, но если не сложно перейдите на на тестовый сайт http://alltruckservice.com.ua
И введите в поиск "180-21", ничего не найдет но удалит "-" тире, а если сразу ввести "18021" то все находит , никак не пойму в чем дело??

Comment: Понял проблему, дополню ответ чуть позже

Comment: Сделал, у меня на сайте работает. http://test.kagg.eu/shop/ введите в поиске `ani-mi`

Comment: Уважаемый  KAGG Design, вы просто гений, уже 3 месяца "гуглоблужу" кто его знает сколько форумов облазил, только Вы дали правильное решение, большое спасибо заработало, то что надо!!!!

Comment: Да ладно, прекратите)

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.